# XLSXWRITER insert_image not working with BytesIO

Tags: xlsxwriter, insert-image

When written directly to xlsx file, insert_image works as intended. But it doesn't work when written to BytesIO object, the image simply doesn't appear.

Comment: You will need to add an example that shows it not working. Here is an [example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images_bytesio.html) from the from the XlsxWriter documentation that shows `insert_image()` working with BytesIO.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had to actually specify image_data parameter for this to work using byte stream.

```
img = 'img.png'
image_file = open(img, 'rb')
image_data = io.BytesIO(image_file.read())
image_file.close()

ws_dashboard.insert_image('A1',img, {'image_data': image_data, 'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})
```